# How can I log all query parameters in an action filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, logging, action-filter

I am implementing a logger that should capture details through an action filter for the purposes of user activity recording and fault finding.

```
   public interface ISessionLogger
    {
        void LogUserActionSummary(int sessionId, string userActionType);    
        void LogUserActionDetail(int session, string userActionType, DateTime userActionStartedUtc, long actionDurationInMilliseconds, string queryParams, string referredFrom);
    }
```

I would like `queryParams` to capture all keys and values from the form collection, route values, action params, json calls and the querystring, which sounds like I would need

`filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider`

but it doesn't seem possible to loop through this. So in my FilterAttribute I have

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var paramList = new List<string>();
    if(filterContext.ActionParameters != null)
    {
        paramList.AddRange(filterContext.ActionParameters.Select(param => String.Format("{0}:{1}", param.Key, param.Value.ToString())));
    }
    if(filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider != null)
    {
        //loop through the valueprovider and save the key value pairs to paramList
    }

    _queryParams = string.Join(",", paramList);
}
```

Is there another way to achieve this within the OnActionExecuting method of an action filter?

Comment: Did you check MSDN for more details about the ValueProvider? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ivalueprovider(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you simply log the entire Request body? This way you will have everything you need to reconstruct the user request.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var stream = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream;
    var data = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    Log(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
}
```

As an alternative you could try logging all `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params` values as well as `filterContext.RouteData` values:

Comment: `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params` will give me server variables as well that I don't want to log. `Request.InputStream` doesn't capture e.g. a username injected through an attribute, so far I have a combination of `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString`, `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form` and `filterContext.ActionParameters`.